# Plot generation mid-function for input information

Tags: r, function, plot, rstudio

I work with large data sets which have multiple and shifting timestamps. As a result I've found the easiest way to identify subsets of data by plotting and identifying the ranges of data I need using these plots.

I'd like to run a function which plots a subset of my data, then allows me to input a variable by looking at the plot (haven't figured out how to automate this step yet) and continue running the function. However, when plotting within the function, the next line will be run before the plot is generated - therefore I cannot see it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
data.initialization <- function(){
  p = c(1,2,3,4,5)  
  l = c(5,6,7,6,5) #initialize some data

  qplot(p,l)       #plot the data so I can see what it looks like

  x = (readline("Input a value based on the plot: "))  #use the information from looking at the plot to input a value

  y = f(x) #do some more operations with the input variable

}
```

Comment: A bit of clarification. I'd really like this to be self contained in Rstudio such that I don't have to generate a plot to PDF or something similar. It would be ideal to have the plot just pop into the plot window mid-function.

Comment: wrap `qplot` in a `print` statement

Comment: @emilliman5 Worked perfectly - too easy! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a print() around the the qplot call to get the output

```
library(ggplot2)
f <- function(z) {
  as.numeric(z)+2
}

data.initialization <- function(){
  p = c(1,2,3,4,5)  
  l = c(5,6,7,6,5) #initialize some data

  print(qplot(p,l))       #plot the data so I can see what it looks like

  x = (readline("Input a value based on the plot: "))  #use the information from looking at the plot to input a value

  y = f(x) #do some more operations with the input variable
  y
} 

data.initialization()
```